# Javascript Client for Windows Azure Service Bus Relay service?

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-servicebusrelay

Is it possible to consume a WCF service via a Windows Azure Service Bus Relay in a JavaScript client?

Comment: I updated my answer after looking into it more.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a `WebHttpRelay` service that can be accessed via `GET` calls in JavaScript if you are using Node.

**EDIT:** [This](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2011/07/02/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-and-wcf/) gives a good overview on how to setup a WCF service to support CORS. You need to enable it on your service to allow calls from a different host.